# Can't use intellisense for Unity because VS code can't find .NETWORK,Version=v4.71 even though it's installed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Sorry, I'm a newbie here. I've spent a few hours now trying to get intellisense to work on VS code and have followed multiple Youtube guides. No luck. I've installed and uninstalled everything multiple times. I keep getting this message.

F:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

It tells me to install the developer pack, but it already is installed? Any idea of how to fix this? Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your installed version is, really, 4.7.1 developer pack?

Answer (score -1):

Primarily, this has to do with the VS code extensions and Installation of the Unity editor on Unity HUB.

In VS code, install the extension: C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).

While installing the unity editor through Unity HUB, make sure you are installing Microsoft visual studio community.

Comment: This has nothing to do with visual studio community.

Comment: @luke so why are they talking of installing Microsoft visual studio community?  Last line.

Comment: @BugFinder Apologies, I misunderstood your first comment. You're correct