# Can't use Intellisense for Unity on VSCode because things are installed on different drives?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Here is the entire error message.

d:\Unity\My project (5)\Assembly-CSharp.csproj F:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

I have .NET Core SDK installed on my F: drive, while I believe the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack is installed on my C: drive. I'm 90% sure that's why VSCode isn't recognizing I have the Developer pack installed, although I really do.

And to try to install the .NET Core SDK on my C: drive, I even disabled my F: drive - however the installer says it can't find the directory to install and refuses to install anywhere else other than the F: drive.

I also notice the error message says something about retargeting the application. Is that something that'd fix this? How would I go about doing this?

I've been troubleshooting this for several hours now and am desperate for help. I'm even willing to pay for a fix at this point. Thank you.

Comment: You already asked this question [Can't use intellisense for Unity because VS code can't find .NETWORK,Version=v4.71 even though it's installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73890271/cant-use-intellisense-for-unity-because-vs-code-cant-find-network-version-v4)

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the developer pack and not just the runtime. And no. I hate vs code

Comment: Yeah, actually I tried installing both just to make sure. No luck.

Comment: Did you try to assign Visual Studio as the external script editor ?

Comment: Yes in Preferences and External Tools i made sure it was VS Code.